# How to undo double-click in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Double-clicking on a cell in Jupyter Noterbook enters the Edit Mode for that cell.
How to revert this action? How to exit the Edit Mode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Edit area has a gray background. On the left of it there is an area with the white background, limited on the left with a vertical bar of green or blue color.
Click that white background and press `<Shift+Enter>`.

Comment: Thank you !!!!!!!  I was like how did that ordinary text get the gray box around it, oh no... I tried hotkeys and other stuff.